# Print xml from new SoapClient

Tags: php, xml, web-services

Im trying to construct a SOAP webservice in php, but I have some problems
Im trying to print in screen a xml header, in order to check with the webservice team if is valid or not.

I create it in this way:

```
class WsseAuthHeader extends SoapHeader 
{
    private $wss_ns = 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd';
    private $wsp_ns = 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText';
    private $wsu_ns = 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd';

    function __construct($user, $pass) 
    {

        $auth = new stdClass();
        $auth->username = new SoapVar($user, XSD_STRING, NULL, $this->wss_ns, NULL, $this->wss_ns);
        $auth->password = new SoapVar($pass, XSD_STRING, NULL, $this->wss_ns, NULL, $this->wsp_ns);

        $username_token = new stdClass();
        $username_token->UsernameToken = new SoapVar($auth, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, NULL, $this->wss_ns, 'UsernameToken', $this->wsu_ns);

        //echo "<pre>"; print_r($username_token); exit();

        $security_sv = new SoapVar(
            new SoapVar($username_token, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, NULL, $this->wss_ns, 'UsernameToken', $this->wss_ns),
            SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, NULL, $this->wss_ns, 'Security', $this->wss_ns);
        parent::__construct($this->wss_ns, 'Security', $security_sv, true);
    }
}
```

Then, I try to call webservice and print the xml:

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://xxxxxx?wsdl", array('trace' => 1));
$client->__setSoapHeaders(Array(new WsseAuthHeader("myuser", "mypass")));

$result = $client->myfunction(51000286);
echo "REQUEST:\n" . $client->__getLastRequest() . "\n";
```

I saw __getLastRequest() in php.net manual, but it doesn´t work
I only can see "java.lang.NullPointerException"

Is there another method?
I need the generated xml to check it with webservice guys.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Okay, let's see if we can get things straight. I think you want to build a client in PHP which consumes a web service build by another team, 'webservice guys'.  

If that is the case, you will be in for quite a task. I can explain how to do it, but before that, I first have to know if that is what you want.

Comment: I need to see the xml header, because, they told me, the xml header is empty, and I don´t think so. I guess, my function should generate a "SoapHeader", and I guess this is a xml

Comment: No that is probably not what you should do. Yo just should call a method on the web service (with your client, which you have to build) and after that you can investigate anything you like. Yo should not really care about the header. If you can see the web service WSDL, you can send a request to the web sevice and you will receive an answer, which will have a header and it will not be empty... Why do the 'webservice guys' tell you the header is empty? What header?

Comment: because the java.lang.NullPointerException, they have a log and they can see user and password is empty, and this can´t be empty. So, I want to check the generated header. what __setSoapHeaders does? send a header? xml header?

Comment: Okay, forget what I said and let's just focus on 'Why __getLastRequest()' does not show the last request'. What is your PHP version. It should be >= 5.0.1. And what method on the web service are you calling? As far as I can see you are not doing a request, so calling last request is of no use at all. (Note: and if you do only one request and it fails, you wont see anything either).

Comment: Php version is 5.3.8. Im calling to "myfunction" in the line $result = $client->myfunction(51000286), with that value

Answer (score 0):

I could solve using:

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://xxxxxxx?wsdl", array('trace' => 1,'exceptions'=>0));
```